# parent process not reading the data from named pipe completely

Tags: c++, c

I am trying to fork a process and execute a command. i am creating a named pipe and trying to execute the command from the child process which writes the STDOUT to pipe. parent process will read from the pipe. my problem is that the parent process is not reading the data from the pipe completely. here is the code.

```
fifo_fd = mkfifo(MY_FIFO, 0666);
FILE *fp = fdopen(fifo_fd, "r");
childpid = fork();
if (childpid == 0)
{
   dup2(fifo_fd, STDOUT_FILENO);
   dup2(fifo_fd, STDERR_FILENO);
   close(fifo_fd);
   execv(arg_list[0], arg_list);
   _exit (127);
}
else
{
   //parent process
   if(waitpid(childpid, &status,WNOHANG ) == -1) {
     // now we kill the child and return failure.
   }

   fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);

   while((fgets(buf, sizeof(buf)-1,fp))) {
   strcat(result,buf); //we copy the buf to result
}
return success;
}
```

Comment: Well, you have a serious flaw in your reading: you are waiting for the child to die before you actually start reading. Which means you are relying on things to completely fit into whatever buffers the system provides; anything beyond that will cause a deadlock. Whether or not this could also cause the symptoms you are seeing is something I can't tell, though.

Comment: @ChristianStieber: the WNOHANG option will make sure the waitpid dosent hang right? i am able to read from the pipe in the parent process, but it dosent read completely

Answer (score 0):

You want to be using a pipe, not a fifo, that way you don't need to create a filesystem entry. As @Christian says, you also need to make sure both processes run concurrently, otherwise the pipe/fifo may block and cause your program to hang.

Try something like the following.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int pipe_fd[2];
    pipe(pipe_fd);

    if (fork() == 0) {
        dup2(pipe_fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        dup2(pipe_fd[1], STDERR_FILENO);
        close(pipe_fd[0]);
        close(pipe_fd[1]);
        char *arg_list[] = {"/bin/echo", "hello", 0};
        execv(arg_list[0], arg_list);
        __builtin_unreachable();

    } else {
        close(pipe_fd[1]);
        char buf[32];
        int count;
        for (;;) {
            count = read(pipe_fd[0], buf, sizeof(buf));
            if (count <= 0) break;
            write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, count);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: does blocking read() return when a function like alarm(nsecs); fires?

Comment: Yes, `alarm` sends a signal, so `read` will return with `EINTR`.

Comment: when the SIGALRM is sent, the program terminates right? how do we handle when the read terminates with EINTR?

Comment: You need to make sure `SIGALRM` doesn't cause the program to terminate, otherwise `read` will never return. Look at `sigaction`.